# Set computer to ONLY allow remote login, not local

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

We have a Windows 7 computer that, do to some security rules, we would like to configure to ONLY allow remote access. That is, someone would not be able to log in by connecting a keyboard/mouse/monitor directly to the computer, preferably with an exception for admins. **Is this even possible? If so, how would one do this?** Note that we haven't fully thought through whether this is a *good* solution or not, as we don't know if it's even doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the "Allow log on locally" local/group policy to determine which users can logon to a server.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221980.aspx

or Deny log on locally if you have a shorter list....

This should allow Remote connections set up via "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services" policy